# # symbol in tel: links not working on nokia devices

Tags: nokia, tel

I have a html page with links like < a href="tel:*123#">*123#< /a>.

when user clicks on the link from a nokia device (tested with N73, E72) it says 'invalid phone number'.
I have found that numbers without the # symbol are dialed out fine.

Just wondering if there's a specific reason for this restriction and is there a way to encode those numbers so that they work from nokia devices.

Deepak.

Comment: did you tried to use entities instead of * and # ?

Comment: use html entities, like &entity_name;

Comment: Don't forget, "#" and "*" are reserved characters and you will need to URL encode them. Usually as <a href="tel:%2A123%23"> You can find out more about percent encoding at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding